# Navigation Bar Extension iOS

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I want to create an extension for my navigation bar just like in the image with the segmented control. I tried to search the web but I couldn't find anything. Is it only available for Apple developers? Pls help

Cheers,

Palash

[image]

Comment: So, you might overthink that? Or do you have other questions?

Answer (score 0):

So, you have to understand that it's not about the navigation bar. It's just a simple `UIViewController` with two UI segments which are `UISegmentControl` and `UITableView`(Left screen shot). On the right hand side, it's just a `UITableViewController` with `UISearchBar`.

Comment: But how do I create that `UIViewContoller`

Comment: What do you mean how do you create `UIViewController`?